# JS handling of network error

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm wondering how i could handle this kind of error occuring during my ajax request :
[image]

The fact is I know this will append, and i want to prevent the user when it occurs.

I tried to use the function onabort, onerror (which is activated, but i can't figure it out what's kind of error it is).

[image]

```
    xhttp.onabort = function () {
        debug("abort")
    };
    xhttp.onerror = function () {
        displayErreur("The service is non-recheable now") //standard message for all error
        debug("test " + this)
        dump(this.upload)
    };
```

Thanks you by advance :)

Comment: Post **code**, not *pictures* of code. [Here's why](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247).

Comment: Most probably, you're using self signed certificate

Comment: Yes it's a self signed certificate, I know it and I want to prevent the user to accept it via a standard navigator